# <!--[if IE6]> block doesn't work

Tags: css, if-statement, internet-explorer-6

```
<!--[if IE6]>
        #refresh{
            position:absolute;
            left:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.clientWidth-this.offsetWidth)-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginLeft,10)||0)-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginRight,10)||100));
            top:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginTop,10)||0)-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginBottom,10)||50)));
        }
    <![endif]-->
```

This code block intend to solve the problem that ie6 doesn't recognise

> position : fixed;

But it doesn't run unless I add something into the if block.

```
<!--[if IE6]>
        body{}//just like this
        #refresh{
            position:absolute;
            left:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.clientWidth-this.offsetWidth)-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginLeft,10)||0)-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginRight,10)||100));
            top:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginTop,10)||0)-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginBottom,10)||50)));
        }
    <![endif]-->
```

Could you tell me why did it happen?

Comment: Please specify the language in which you'r doing coding

Comment: It's a css code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `<style>` tag:

```
<!--[if IE6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #refresh{
            position:absolute;
            /* ... */
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```